# Convert Javascript code, that changes DOM element's background color, to JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-manipulation, jscolor

I am new in jQuery and still learning. My problem is I don't know how to convert the following javascript code to jQuery.

Javacript:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('p-bg')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color
```

Thanks in advance guys.

By the way this is the full code:

```
<input class="color" onchange="document.getElementsByClassName('p-bg')[0].style.backgroundColor = '#'+this.color">
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

`$(".color")` [jQuery class selector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

`.change` [.change() form events](https://api.jquery.com/change/)

`.eq()` [.eq() filter elements](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

`.css()` [.css() manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$(".color").change(function(){
    $(".p-bg").eq(0).css("background-color", $(this).css("color"));
})
```

<kbd>Note</kbd> `document.getElementsByClassName('p-bg')[0]` in jQuery is equivalent to `$(".p-bg").eq(0)`

Remember that in `jQuery`, the [DOM](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) must be loaded to start working, eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //You jQuery code here...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.p-bg:first').css('backgroundColor','"#"+this.color');
```

Comment: Yes, better answer imho

Comment: @MauricePerry - Maybe, but a small explanation would result in an even better answer

Answer (score 0):

The `change` function binds a function that will execute onchange of the selection set which is in our case all elements with class = 'color'.

`$(this)` within the function will refer to the current DOM element onchange in the selection, so in this way we catch it's color property.

`$('.p-bg:first')`, here we are selecting all elements with class p-bg, and to obtain the first element we are using the :first Pseudo Class Selector, then using the `css` jquery function, we are defining the css property in the first paramerter `'backgroundColor'` and the value of the property in the second parameter using another css property (the color) of the current element `$(this).css("color")`.

When we use css function with one parameter it will return the value, with 2 parameter we will be setting the value.

The code below will be the change in jquery.

```
$(".color").change(function(){

    $('.p-bg:first').css('backgroundColor', $(this).css("color")); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to look alike that as you have used Js in your html, this will work for you (Only one line code):

```
<input class="color" onchange="$(this).css('background-color',$(this).css('color'))">
```

But i will recommend you to create a change function and then work on it.

Html:

```
<input class="color">
```

Script:

```
<script>
$('.color').on('change',function(){
    $(this).css('background-color',$(this).css('color'));
});
</script>
```

Explanation:

`$(this)` will get this element for you. then using `.css('background-color',$(this).css('color'))` will assign its color to its background.